# Can Set-AzWebAppSlot overwrite just 1 Application Setting?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-appservice

Reading the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/set-azwebappslot?view=azps-4.3.0

It says:

*App Settings HashTable. Existing App Settings will be replaced, removing any settings that are not provided.*

Does that mean if I only provide one value in that hashtable parameter, all my app settings variable get blown away that aren't in parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `Set-AzWebAppSlot` cannot overwrite just one app setting, it will overwrite all the settings.

If you want to overwrite just one app setting, you could use the commands below.

In my sample, I just overwrite the app setting named `setting2` with the value `value2`.

```
$r = Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config -ResourceName "<webapp-name>/<slot-name>/appsettings" -Action list -ApiVersion 2018-02-01 -Force
$r.Properties.setting2 = "value2"
New-AzResource -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config -ResourceName "<webapp-name>/<slot-name>/appsettings" -Properties $r.properties -ApiVersion 2018-02-01 -Force
```

[image]